# Typescript typebox: static initialization

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, typebox

I have two classes where I want to define a static `Schema` property using [typebox](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@sinclair/typebox). I also need to define a dependency between the two classes: first class schema must have an array of type of the second class schema:

```
import {Type, Static} from '@sinclair/typebox';

class ClassA {
    static Schema = Type.Object({
        id: Type.String(),
        data: Type.Array(ClassB.Schema) // ERROR: <-- Property 'Schema' is used before its initialization.
    })
    
    constructor(id: string, data: ClassB[]) {
        this.id = id;
        this.data = data;
    }
    
    public id: string;
    public data: ClassB[];
}

class ClassB {
    static Schema = Type.Object({
        id: Type.String(),
    })

    constructor(id: string) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    
    public id: string;
}
```

Problem is I can't pass `ClassB.Schema` as argument for `Type.Array()`, I got the error: `Property 'Schema' is used before its initialization`. I thought that since both are static properties, they are evaluated at the same time but it doesn't seem the case. Any idea how to workaround this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems it is enough to invert the order of class declarations...

```
import {Type, Static} from '@sinclair/typebox';

class ClassB {
    static Schema = Type.Object({
        id: Type.String(),
    })

    constructor(id: string) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public id: string;
}

class ClassA {
    static Schema = Type.Object({
        id: Type.String(),
        data: Type.Array(ClassB.Schema)
    })

    constructor(id: string, data: ClassB[]) {
        this.id = id;
        this.data = data;
    }

    public id: string;
    public data: ClassB[];
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you get a different error anyways? It should be something along the lines of "Cannot access ClassB before initialization"

Comment: It doesn't seem so @vera.